# Look for multiple words in praat script

Tags: phonetics, praat

I am writing a praat script that will search through multiple files for a list of words. This is what I have so far. It only zooms in to the first word in the procedure, and doesn't loop through the rest. I think this has something to do with what is selected. For the `For i through n`, only the text grid is selected, but then in the annotator, both are selected. I need the script to continue searching through each interval so that the other words in the procedure can be found as well.

```
directory$ = "directory"
listfile$ = "test.txt"

Read Strings from raw text file... 'directory$'/'listfile$'
last = Get number of strings

# loop through each file
for a from 1 to last
    listfile2$ = listfile$ - ".txt"
    select Strings 'listfile2$'
    textgrid$ = Get string... 'a'
    Read from file... 'directory$'/'textgrid$'
    object_name$ = selected$("TextGrid")

    Read from file... 'directory$'/'object_name$'.wav

    # rearrange tiers 
    select TextGrid 'object_name$'
    Duplicate tier: 3, 1, "MAU"
    Remove tier: 4
    Insert interval tier: 1, "subphone"

    # find target word
    n = Get number of intervals: 3  
    for i to n

@instance: "strikes"
@instance: "raindrops"
@instance: "and"
@instance: "rainbow"
@instance: "into"
@instance: "round"
@instance: "its"
@instance: "its"

procedure instance: .target_word$

    label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i
        if label$ == .target_word$
        index = i
        i += n

# get the start and end point of the word
startpoint = Get starting point... 3 index
endpoint = Get end point... 3 index

        select TextGrid 'object_name$'
        plus Sound 'object_name$'
        View & Edit
        editor TextGrid 'object_name$'

# annotation
Select... startpoint endpoint
Zoom to selection
pause Annotate stops then continue
Close
endeditor

        endif # if the label = target word
    endfor # for number of intervals



select TextGrid 'object_name$'
Write to text file: directory$ + "/" + object_name$ + "_editedtext.TextGrid"

select all
minus Strings 'listfile2$'
Remove

endproc

#writeInfoLine: "done!"
#select Strings 'listfile2$'
endfor # for each of the files
clearinfo
print That's it!
```

Edit: Here's the revised script, based on the answer.

```
directory$ = "/Users/directorypath"
listfile$ = "test.txt"

Read Strings from raw text file... 'directory$'/'listfile$'
last = Get number of strings
listfile2$ = listfile$ - ".txt"

# loop through each file
for a from 1 to last
    select Strings 'listfile2$'
    textgrid$ = Get string... 'a'
    Read from file... 'directory$'/'textgrid$'
    object_name$ = selected$("TextGrid")
    Read from file... 'directory$'/'object_name$'.wav

    # rearrange tiers
    select TextGrid 'object_name$'
    Duplicate tier: 3, 1, "MAU"
    Remove tier: 4
    Insert interval tier: 1, "subphone"

    n = Get number of intervals: 3

    for i to n
        @instance: "strikes"
        @instance: "raindrops"
        @instance: "and"
        @instance: "rainbow"
        @instance: "into"
        @instance: "round"
        @instance: "its"
        @instance: "its"

    endfor
endfor

procedure instance: .target_word$

label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i
if label$ == .target_word$
    index = i
    i += n

    # get the start and end point of the word
    startpoint = Get starting point... 3 index
    endpoint = Get end point... 3 index

    select TextGrid 'object_name$'
    plus Sound 'object_name$'
    View & Edit
    editor TextGrid 'object_name$'

    # annotation
    Select... startpoint endpoint
    Zoom to selection
    pause Annotate stops then continue
    Close
    endeditor

    endif

endproc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script you wrote was not very carefully indented, so I tried formatting it so that it would be easier to understand what was going on. And in a sense, it did. But what surfaced took some effort to understand nevertheless.

Here's a step-by-step follow-through on what's going on, as Praat sees it:

1. In line 8 you start a for loop: `for a from 1 to last`
2. Inside that loop, in line 25, you start a second one: `for i to n`
3. Inside that second loop, in line 27, you call a procedure named `instance`.

   At this point, Praat skips to the *last* line that defines that procedure (so if you define it a number of times, you only get the last one). Since there is only one, Praat jumps to line 36: `procedure instance: .target_word$`
4. Inside that procedure (which, by the way, is defined inside a for loop, which is ... unusual) you have an `if` block: `if label$ == .target_word$`
5. At the end of that block, the `endfor` increments the *control variable* (in this case, `i`) and closes the `for` loop. But **which one**?

   You might expect it to close the last for loop that we entered (that's what I did). But actually, Praat seems to keep track of opening `for` and closing `endfor` statements, and maps them vertically.

   I haven't looked at the interpreter in enough detail to figure out *exactly* what happens, but in a case like this, the results are the same as mapping the lowest `endfor` (= the one closest to the bottom of your script) to the highest `for`, and so on.

   (This is likely *not* what really happens (otherwise multiple non-overlapping loops wouldn't work), but this is not really important: what is important is that **an `endfor` only closes *a single* `for`, regardless of where in the script it is or when Praat sees it**. As an aside, this is *not* what happens with `endproc`.)

   Regardless of the precise rules this `endfor` gets mapped to the second `for`, which we entered in point 2 (that was line 25). So we go back to the first line of *that* loop (line 26).
6. Now we get to line 27 *for the second time* (this time for the second interval) and we again call `@instance: "strikes"`. We still haven't got to `@instance: "raindrops"`!
7. This repeats for all the intervals, each time incrementing `i` by one (whenever we hit the `endfor`), until `i` becomes `n`. This time, when we call `@instance`, we go through the `if` block and we once again get to the `endfor` from point 5.

   Praat obediently increments the control variable (so now `i = n + 1`), and checks the end condition set at the start of the for loop. In this case, Praat knows the for loop ends when `i == n`, and since `i = n + 1`, instead of jumping back to the top, it keeps going.

   **Only now**, after having gone through all the intervals of the first file, **do we actually get to the end of the procedure**!
8. The procedure finally ends. Praat remembers that we entered this procedure way back in point 3, and back then we were reading line 27. So, dutifully, it goes and reads line 28, which is another call to the same procedure: `@instance: "raindrops"`.
9. And here's where (finally!) it dies.

   It dies because the control variable `i` is now `n + 1` (it became that in point 7). This would not normally happen, since you would not normally hit an `endfor` statement for a loop that has already finished. But in this case we do. So when Praat tries to read the label of interval `i` in a TextGrid with `i-1` intervals... it complains saying that the interval number is too large. Because it is.

   Your initial problem (it doing only part of the work, and not actually dying) I cannot reproduce because in the `if` block you actually manually change the value of `i` (which is *risky*), and that `if` block only gets executed if the label matches early enough in your TextGrid (early enough so that it happens before the script explodes).

You can see this whole mess in action with this simplified version of the structure of your script:

```
last = 10
for a from 1 to last
  appendInfoLine: "First line of main loop; a = ", a

  n = 5 
  for i to n
    appendInfoLine: "First line of second loop; i = ", i

    @instance: "strikes"
    @instance: "raindrops"
    @instance: "and"

    procedure instance: .target_word$
      appendInfoLine: "Called @instance: " + .target_word$
      appendInfoLine: "a=", a, " i=", i

  endfor # for number of intervals

      appendInfoLine: "End of @instance"
    endproc

  appendInfoLine: "Script claims we are done!"
endfor # for each of the files
```

To fix this, you should probably re-structure your code so that it follows more or less this pattern:

```
for a to last
  for i to n
    @instance: "word"
  endfor
endfor

procedure instance: .word$
  # do things
endproc
```

This has been highly educational. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely educational. I've cleaned up my script a lot. However, I'm still having the same problem in the if loop. I get the error message "get label of interval not available for current selection" (I guess because both the text grid and sound are selected at that point.) I'm not sure how to fix it so that it is a loop and just the text grid is selected - or maybe this isn't even the problem. I'm pasting my new script in my original post.

Comment: It looks like you already figured out the answer. Kudos! But if I were you I would have kept the original version of the script in your question. Specially since I make many references to it by line number, and now those will make very little sense to people newly coming to this question. You should still be able to see the original script by looking at your question's edit history, though. But it's an extra step.

Answer (score 1):

Try and add `select TextGrid 'object_name$'` just after the procedure init.

```
procedure instance: .target_word$

    select TextGrid 'object_name$'

    label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i
    if label$ == .target_word$
         index = i
         i += n
```

Comment: I think this worked, but now I'm getting an error message: "Interval too big: Script line 48 not performed or completed << label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i >> Menu command "Run" not completed."

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! The [manual page](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting_3_6___For__loops.html) on for loops was helpful. Here's the code if anyone finds it useful.

```
#############################################################
#
# This script requires a file listing the .Textgrid files 
# in the directory containing the .wav files and .Textgrid files.
# Using the command line, you can make this by navigating to the directory,
# and typing ls *.TextGrid > contents.txt
#
# This script reads in files and textgrids from a directory,
# rearranges the tiers that were output by MAUS, - http://www.bas.uni-muenchen.de/Bas/BasMAUS.html
# provides a subphone tier, searches for words specified in the procedure
# so that they can be annotated.
#
# Written using code from Bert Remijsen that was rewritten by Peggy Renwick
#
#############################################################

# enter your directory here
directory$ = "/Users/lisalipani/Documents/School/Graduate/Research/NSP/CorpusFiles/Test"

# enter your list file here
listfile$ = "test.txt"

Read Strings from raw text file... 'directory$'/'listfile$'
last = Get number of strings
listfile2$ = listfile$ - ".txt"

# loop through each file
for a from 1 to last
    select Strings 'listfile2$'
    textgrid$ = Get string... 'a'
    Read from file... 'directory$'/'textgrid$'
    object_name$ = selected$("TextGrid")
    Read from file... 'directory$'/'object_name$'.wav

    # rearrange tiers
    select TextGrid 'object_name$'
    Duplicate tier: 3, 1, "MAU"
    Remove tier: 4
    Insert interval tier: 1, "subphone"

    # input target words here
    @instance: "strikes"
    @instance: "friends"

    # start the procedure
    procedure instance: .target_word$

    select TextGrid 'object_name$'

    numberOfIntervals = Get number of intervals: 3

    for intervalNumber from 1 to numberOfIntervals
        label$ = Get label of interval: 3, intervalNumber
        if label$ == .target_word$

            # get the start and end point of the word
            startpoint = Get starting point... 3 intervalNumber
            endpoint = Get end point... 3 intervalNumber

            select TextGrid 'object_name$'
            plus Sound 'object_name$'
            View & Edit
            editor TextGrid 'object_name$'

            # annotation
            Select... startpoint endpoint
            Zoom to selection
            pause Annotate stops then continue
            Close
            endeditor

            select TextGrid 'object_name$'

        endif
    endfor
    endproc

    select TextGrid 'object_name$'
    Save as text file... 'directory$'/'object_name$'_annotated.TextGrid

endfor
appendInfoLine: "all done!"
```